# How to change LUIS application for a chatbot in the .BOT file?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot using botbuilder SDK V4 for Node.js and Microsoft Azure services …

In the `.bot` file, we find the encrypted LUIS app informations.

```
{
  "type": "luis",
  "name": "luis",
  "appId": <appId>,
  "authoringKey": <authoringKey>,
  "subscriptionKey": <subscriptionKey>,
  "version": "0.1",
  "region": <region>,
  "id": <id>
}
```

My question is how to change the LUIS app used by my bot in the .bot file?

in the LUIS endpoint, there is a parameter called staging, which will specify if I am using the LUIS app in staging or production mode.

So, how to specify the staging or production mode in the .bot file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

You cannot use a Staging slot by just editing the configuration of your bot.

But you can use staging with the Options of the Recognizer, so use another parameter to activate Staging use.

---

### Details - Use of Staging vs Production in LUIS

Technically speaking, the difference between calls to `Staging` versus `Production` slots of a LUIS app can be seen in the URL called, where there is a
`staging=true` field:

- Staging: `https://_AzureRegion_.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/_AppId_?staging=true&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=60&subscription-key=_YourKey_&q=_YourQuery_`
- Prod: `https://_AzureRegion_.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/_AppId_?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=60&subscription-key=_YourKey_&q=_YourQuery_`

### Implementation in Bot Builder

You can see in the BotBuilder sources that `staging` is never used in the configuration. But, in the class called `LuisRecognizer`, you can pass `options` where there is a `staging` boolean, see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS/LuisRecognizer.cs#L280) for .Net, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-ai/src/luisRecognizer.ts#L99) for js.

So in js in your case:

```
// Map the contents to the required format for `LuisRecognizer`.
const luisApplication = {
    applicationId: process.env.appId,
    endpointKey: process.env.subscriptionKey,
    azureRegion: process.env.region
}

// Create configuration for LuisRecognizer's runtime behavior.
const luisPredictionOptions = {
    includeAllIntents: true,
    log: true,
    staging: **POINT TO A CONFIG VARIABLE FOR EXAMPLE**
}

const luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(luisApplication, luisPredictionOptions, true);
```